# Performing a regex replace on a 900 MB logfile

Tags: regex, windows-server-2003

My beloved TextPad says "out of memory" after a while when trying to perform this operation.  Next best (i.e. simplest/fastest) free tool to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install [ActivePerl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads) (only 25MB `.msi` file) and run this one-liner:

```
perl -pe "s/regex/replacement/g" <input.txt >output.txt
```

You can even use it for in-place editing like this:

```
perl -pi.bak -e "s/regex/replacement/g" file.txt
```

Comment: I just happened to have Perl installed.  Thanks!  (@fcorrao I also +1'd you)

Answer (score 6):

Install [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) and use sed to perform the search and replace.

e.g.  sed -e 's/findthis/replacewiththis/g' < /path/to/bigfile > /path/to/newfile